# Coefficients of Linear Combination of Shifted Gaussians

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have summation of a number N of evenly shifted (by d) and identical Gaussian functions f(x). For example:

$f_N (x) = \sum _{i=1} ^N a_i f(x - d \times i)$

I'm attaching a picture below of what this might look like. In blue are the individual Gaussian functions and in red is their sum. I'm trying to determine the coefficients $a_i$ (basically their individual heights) of the individual Gaussians if I can measure their sum $f_N (x)$ and also know their shifting. I assume that $a_i \geq 0$.

Any suggestions on how I could go about this?

[image: Sum of Gaussians]

Answer (score 0):

Take the Fourier transform of the equation you have displayed, keeping in mind the shift theorem of the Fourier transform. Essentially, filter your target function by multiplying in the frequency domain by a Gaussian.

You can also do least squares fitting. Make a new inner product $\langle f,g \rangle = \int f(x) \bar g(x) e^{-x^2} dx$, then product your function onto the shifted Gaussians, using that inner product.